# Opening .grp .mps and .rsc .rsr

Tags: file-extension

I recently re-opened the different editions of **The Cluefinders** to understand how it worked to potentially do a spinoff of it.

I downloaded the iso file from https://www.myabandonware.com/game/cluefinders-3rd-grade-adventures-bh9

Unfortunately, even if it works flawlessly (especially for a game so old), the files still have some secrets I want to uncover.

Primarily there are some .grp, .mps, .rsc and .rsr file that I can open, but cannot read properly. Thus since I can't decode it I can't find the master file that ensures the proper order of events and the different graphics files. There are references in some MPS files but I don't understand how it fetches the different sprites, etc ...

Does anyone know how to open these files properly? I'll try and do the maximum from them

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

It appears those .GRP files contain audio, because the result of a hexdump reveals a string "RGRP Wave" at the bottom of the file. You could probably play around with it in audacity to see if you can produce sounds from inside the game.

In case you didn't discover this, the .smk files open in VLC: they are video files.